# Access covert one row to multiple rows

Tags: sql, select, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have a table called `Student_Course`, which looks like:

```
 ID  | Name  |  Course 1 | Course 2  |  Course 3
 1   | A     |    90    |    50    |     60
 2   | B     |    80    |    70    |     30
 3   | C     |    70    |    60    |     20
```

I want to do some query and covert the above table to the following format:

```
 ID |   Name |  Course Name   |  Score
1   |    A   |   Course 1     |    90       
1   |    A   |   Course 2     |    50
1   |    A   |   Course 3     |    60
2   |    B   |   Course 1     |    80    
2   |    B   |   Course 2     |    70  
2   |    B   |   Course 3     |    30
3   |    C   |   Course 1     |    70     
3   |    C   |   Course 2     |    60        
3   |    C   |   Course 3     |    20
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a couple of `union all` operators:

```
SELECT ID, Name, 'Course 1' AS [Course Name], Course1 AS Score
FROM   Student_Course
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, 'Course 2' AS [Course Name], Course2 AS Score
FROM   Student_Course
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, 'Course 3' AS [Course Name], Course3 AS Score
FROM   Student_Course
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your quick reply. Yes it works. But if there is space between 'course' and '1', e.g. course 1, there is error.

Comment: @Kejiong I did not understand that statement - can you please clarify? Do you want to select `'Course 1'` instead of `'Course1'`?

Comment: yes. I want to select 'Course 1' instead of 'Course1', and also output column name is 'Course Name' instead of 'CourseName'. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mureinik, Thanks. Solved it. Just add '[]'. Thank you.

Comment: @Kejiong Edited accordingly, now that I understood your requirement.